# Force an information window instead of zoom on click and change the icon

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm using [MarkerClusterer](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/) to group markers and I have 2 questions:

1. What should I do to prevent the zoom on click and show an information
   window instead, like when you click a marker?
2. Is there any way to change the icon of the cluster for the
   markers? I don't want to use the earthquake-like icon as a group icon for my markers.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
var marker;
var gm_map;
var markerArray = [];
var address = 'Sweden';
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        gm_map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        gm_map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
    } else {
        alert("Kunde inte genomföra den geologiska inställningen på grund av följande fel:\n\n" + status);
    }
});



function initialize() {
    var marker, i;

    var locations = [["content", 59.328626, 13.485686, 1]];


    var options_googlemaps = {
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 18,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false
    }

    gm_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-maps'), options_googlemaps);


    var options_markerclusterer = {
        gridSize: 20,
        maxZoom: 18
    };

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(gm_map, [], options_markerclusterer, {zoomOnClick: false});
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
        alert('center of cluster: '+cluster.getCenter());
    });



    for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: gm_map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                $('#toggle-photolist').fadeIn();
                $('#close-overlay').fadeIn();
                $('#list-photos').html(locations[i][0]);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        markerArray.push(marker);
        markerCluster.addMarkers(markerArray, true);
    }
}



$(document).ready(function() {

    // INITIERA GOOGLE MAPS
    initialize();

});
```

**WORKING `zoomOnClick`**

```
var options_markerclusterer = {
    gridSize: 20,
    maxZoom: 18,
    zoomOnClick: false
};

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(gm_map, [], options_markerclusterer);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

re 1:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers ,{zoomOnClick: false});
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster,'clusterclick', 
    function(cluster){
      alert('center of cluster: '+cluster.getCenter())
    });
```

The details for the cluster (what info can you get out of it) can be found here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js#801

You can simply show an infoWidow with the center set to cluster.getCenter() in the callback and you will be all set.

re2: Check out this sample with changed icons: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/advanced_example.html

HTH

Comment: Thanks but how should I use `isZoomOnClick`? `isZoomOnClick(false)` didn't work when I was just testing it

Comment: true. I had a look at the implementaion and made a sample , will fix the reply.

Comment: Many thanks! Your demo works as I want it to work but when I use the same code it both shows the alert and zoom the map. Please see my edit in my question for full code.

Comment: Nevermind! I got it working ^^ I replaced the alert with a show/hide function in jQuery and it works as good as your demo now :) Your answer for my second question works as I want it to. Many thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I got it to work because I had an error in the code and that error forced it to not continue the zoom. I have the same problem as I written in my first comment after your last comment. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for the info window, it worked perfectly fine for me! :)

```
    //MarkerCluster!!!
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, my_markers ,{zoomOnClick: false});
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
        var content = '';
        // Convert lat/long from cluster object to a usable MVCObject
        var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
        info.set('position', cluster.center_);
        iw.close();
        iw.setContent('<h1>Hi this is my Info Window</h1>');
        iw.open(map, info);
    });
```

Working example here:
See http://krisarnold.com/2010/10/15/adding-info-windows-to-map-clusters-with-google-maps-api-v3/